# css is causing my form to run off the page on mobile devices

Tags: css, forms, mobile, media-queries

```html
<!-- Main -->
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content">
            <article>
                <!-- Form Code Start -->
                <form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Contact us</legend>
                    
                        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
                        <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
                        <input type='text2'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />
                    
                        <div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>
                    
                        <div>
                            <span class='error'>
                                <?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='container2'>
                            <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
                            <input type='text2' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                            <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='container2'>
                            <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
                            <input type='text2' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
                            <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='container2'>
                            <label for='phone' >Phone Number:</label><br/>
                            <input type='text2' name='phone' id='phone' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('phone') ?>' maxlength="15" /><br/>
                            <span id='contactus_phone_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='container2'>
                            <label for='query_type' >Regarding:</label><br/>
                            <select name='query_type'>
                                <option>Support</option>
                                <option>Request A Quote</option>
                                <option>Trouble uploading a file</option>
                                <option>Other</option>
                            </select>
                            <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class='container2'>
                            <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
                            <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                            <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('message') ?></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class='container2'>
                            <div><img alt='Captcha image' src='show-captcha.php?rand=1' id='scaptcha_img' /></div>
                            <label for='scaptcha' >Enter the code above here:</label>
                            <input type='text2' name='scaptcha' id='scaptcha' maxlength="10" /><br/>
                            <span id='contactus_scaptcha_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                            <div class='short_explanation'>Can't read the image?
                            <a href='javascript: refresh_captcha_img();'>Click here to refresh</a>.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='container2'>
                            <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#contactus fieldset{
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    margin:0 auto;
    width:459px;
}

#contactus legend, h2{
    font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;
}

#contactus label2{
    font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
} 

/* #contactus input[type="text2"], textarea{
    font-family : Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    line-height:140%;
    color : #000; 
    padding : 3px; 
    border : 1px solid #999;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#contactus input[type="text2"]{
    height:26px;
    width:459px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#contactus #scaptcha{
    width:80px;
    height:26px;
}

#contactus input[type="submit2"]{
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    padding-left:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;   
}

#contactus textarea2{
    height:120px;
    width:469px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;  
}

 #contactus input[type="text2"]:focus,textarea:focus{
     color : #009;
     border : 1px solid #0E0D0D;
     background-color : #D1E7FF;
     font-weight:bold;
}

 #contactus .container2{
     margin-top:8px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contactus .error{
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; 
    font-size: 0.7em;
    color: #900;
    background-color : #FF8088;
}

#contactus fieldset#antispam{
    padding:2px;
    border-top:1px solid #EEE;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
    border-bottom:0;
    width:350px;
}

#contactus fieldset#antispam legend{
    font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#333;   
}

#contactus .short_explanation{
    font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color:#333;   
}

/* spam_trap: This input is hidden. This is here to trick the spam bots*/
#contactus .spmhidip{
    display:none;
    width:10px;
    height:3px;
}
#fg_crdiv{
    font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.3em;
    opacity: .2;
    -moz-opacity: .2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);   
}
#fg_crdiv p{
    display:none;
}
```

I've tried everything, I can't figure out what is affecting the form to cause it to run off the screen on a mobile device.  [Here is the link to the form.](https://www.munroprinting.com/upload/contactform.php)

Comment: My thought is that you have not tried "everything", but lets see the code that you have tried

Comment: it will not allow me to past the entire page of code on here

Comment: If you are using bootstrap you shouldn't need to code any media queries at all just wrap your page content in the container div

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap

Comment: Do you mean to have large portion of your css commented out? The `*/`

Comment: no, I accidentally put that in there

Answer (score 0):

in main.css you have hard-coded some widths for example width of input fields, width of fieldset. Just remove them or make them in percentage and your page will become responsive

Comment: it's still not changing, is there something I missed? and now the desktop view is messed up. the form spreads across the container on desktop

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from the snippet but when the following code is placed in the document inspector it seems to work

Your hard coded widths were causing the issue, you may have to also modify your other media queries and break points to get it working at every size

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 736px){
    body, input, select, textarea {
        line-height: 2em;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #contactus input[type="text2"] {
        height: 26px;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://www.munroprinting.com/assets/css/main.css">
<div class="container">
  <div id="content">
    <article>
      <!-- Form Code Start -->
      <form id="contactus" action="/upload/contactform.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Contact us</legend>

          <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="id3a31ca8adb123c3ea7b9" value="432ce4949a45b03c0299f37b81305012">
          <input type="text2" class="spmhidip" name="sp5d7f1e2089582b5699eab58b16dad351">

          <div class="short_explanation">* required fields</div>

          <div><span class="error"></span></div>
          <div class="container2">
            <label for="name">Your Full Name*: </label><br>
            <input type="text2" name="name" id="name" value="" maxlength="50" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAABHklEQVQ4EaVTO26DQBD1ohQWaS2lg9JybZ+AK7hNwx2oIoVf4UPQ0Lj1FdKktevIpel8AKNUkDcWMxpgSaIEaTVv3sx7uztiTdu2s/98DywOw3Dued4Who/M2aIx5lZV1aEsy0+qiwHELyi+Ytl0PQ69SxAxkWIA4RMRTdNsKE59juMcuZd6xIAFeZ6fGCdJ8kY4y7KAuTRNGd7jyEBXsdOPE3a0QGPsniOnnYMO67LgSQN9T41F2QGrQRRFCwyzoIF2qyBuKKbcOgPXdVeY9rMWgNsjf9ccYesJhk3f5dYT1HX9gR0LLQR30TnjkUEcx2uIuS4RnI+aj6sJR0AM8AaumPaM/rRehyWhXqbFAA9kh3/8/NvHxAYGAsZ/il8IalkCLBfNVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%;"><br>
            <span id="contactus_name_errorloc" class="error"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="container2">
            <label for="email">Email Address*:</label><br>
            <input type="text2" name="email" id="email" value="" maxlength="50"><br>
            <span id="contactus_email_errorloc" class="error"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="container2">
            <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label><br>
            <input type="text2" name="phone" id="phone" value="" maxlength="15"><br>
            <span id="contactus_phone_errorloc" class="error"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="container2">
            <label for="query_type">Regarding:</label><br>
            <select name="query_type">
        <option>Support</option>
        <option>Request A Quote</option>
        <option>Trouble uploading a file</option>
        <option>Other</option>
    </select>
            <span id="contactus_email_errorloc" class="error"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="container2">
            <label for="message">Message:</label><br>
            <span id="contactus_message_errorloc" class="error"></span>
            <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="container2">
            <div><img alt="Captcha image" src="show-captcha.php?rand=1" id="scaptcha_img"></div>
            <label for="scaptcha">Enter the code above here:</label>
            <input type="text2" name="scaptcha" id="scaptcha" maxlength="10"><br>
            <span id="contactus_scaptcha_errorloc" class="error"></span>
            <div class="short_explanation">Can't read the image?
              <a href="javascript: refresh_captcha_img();">Click here to refresh</a>.</div>
          </div>


          <div class="container2">
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
          </div>

        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </article>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do I need to remove the original code for those before I enter the media query? it doesn't seem to do anything on the mobile site

Comment: it might be simpler to remove all your media queries and build them up as needed. Remember that the order in which they are loaded is critical to how they are interpreted

Comment: so would where I placed the line of code have something to do with it not working?

Comment: @user7436497 yes! very much yes. put that block i posted at the very end of your css file and see if that works

Comment: does it automatically update? what were the changes you made?

Comment: i edited it so you will need to Copy and paste it to the end of your css file again

Comment: it's still not changing the mobile version

Comment: welll i am only going off the code that i pasted. try to copy that code to a new doc and see if that is working (since you did not post code here )

Comment: should I change the widths of the text areas etc.?

Comment: so where the css is for the form, I'm replacing it with the media query snippet? I just want to make sure before I make the change

Comment: I have no idea where you have your css if you place the block above at the very end of all your css it should be fine. i did not go through your whole file to reconcile it

Comment: I wish I could place the entire file in this post.

Comment: I recommend that you paste a smaller workable piece of your code here so we can help you figure it out read more here [mcve]

Comment: I've just posted the snippet for the form but I think there's something inside the css file that is clashing with the css for the form to cause it from doing this I just can't figure out what.

Comment: that was just css, can you post the html as well?

Comment: html Is up too, not the entire page however, just the code for the form

Comment: any other ideas on what I could do?

Comment: hey, so I figured out what's messing with the mobile version, it's the css rule in fieldset for the margin and width I removed those and the mobile version worked perfectly, but now the desktop version is messed up